# Applying Haar to bitmap image using matlab

Tags: matlab, dwt

I using the following code in matlab to attempt to apply haar dwt to bitmap image

```
im = imread('image.bmp');
[LL,LH,HL,HH] = dwt2(im,'haar');  
 figure; imshow(im);
```

I am getting the following error: Undefined function 'dwt2' for input arguments of type 'uint8'
I have just downloaded the wavelet toolbox.
I thought dwt accepted uint8 type??

Comment: Check the toolbox is properly installed and the function is on your path (`which dwt2` from command line should show it).

Comment: I'm sorry could you be more specific??

Comment: Type `which dwt2` into your commandline. If the toolbox is properly installed, it should return the location of the file. If it doesn't, you need to change your `path` to include the location of the toolbox, because MATLAB doesn't search your entire harddrive to find a function.

Comment: thank you! it is not recognising it. How do I change the path??

Comment: @user1877082 addpath('folder_where_you_have_the_toolbox_instaled').

Answer (score 0):

"Undefined function" errors are commonly not because of the wrong type of input argument, but because MATLAB can't find the file. To call a function it should be:

1. In an *.m file with the same name as the function (e.g. `myfunc.m` for `function myfunc`)
2. In the current working folder **or** on the MATLAB path, which tells MATLAB where to look for files.

Normally when installing a MATLAB toolbox it will automatically be added to the path, but third-party toolboxes often need to be manually added.  Make sure you add all subdirectories as well. You can do this using `genpath` in addition to `addpath`:

```
addpath(genpath('c:/matlab/mytoolbox'))
```

There is also a graphical interface for changing the MATLAB path, accessible from the commandline by typing `pathtool`. Again, for a toolbox, use "Add with Subfolders".

Comment: Thank you for your help, I purchased the toolbox separately and it was in the wrong folder, sorted now,thanks again for your time and help :)